# How to use Guava Optionals in a non-generic context?

Tags: java, guava, option-type, null-object-pattern

I'm trying to use the Null-Objects from guava in the following method:

```
private void display(Optional<String> message) {
  ...
}
```

The method in which I am calling the method display(..) looks like this:

```
if(...) {
  display(Optional.of("hello");
} else {
  display(Optional.absent());
}
```

Now I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
The method display(Optional<String>) in the type TokenServlet is not
applicable for the arguments (Optional<Object>)
```

The only compiling workaround I have found is to use

```
Optional.fromNullable((String) null)
```

instead of

```
Optional.absent()
```

Is there really no other possibility if I'm using Optionals in a non-generic context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
display(Optional.<String> absent());
```

Comment: Note that Java 8 should do the appropriate type inference there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to pass unvalid parameter to method. You have to wrap it in method. It will solve the issue.

```
private void display(String message) {
 Optional<String> optionalMessage=Optional.fromNullable(message);
  ...
}
```

Comment: No method is needed. But it helps as using a local variable allows Java to infer the right generic type.